How can I create a custom C++20 view (like std::ranges::views::filter)
I am looking for a clear resource or tutorial on how to create a custom view in C++20. (like std::ranges::views::filter).
I have checked Microsoft and cppreference documentation but couldn't find specific guidance.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

You have about 30 examples in your compiler's <ranges> header.
